# Normal distribution `N(mu, 1)>1.96`

Tags: r

I try to write an R code to find value of `mu` s.t. the Normal distribution satisfies the probability `P(N(mu, 1)>1.96)=0.95` (i.e., `P(Z>1.96)=0.95` where `Z~N(mu, 1)` and `mu` is what I want to get). Is there any code for solving the parameter of distribution? It seems that this will be a integral equation about `mu` such that

`int_{1.96}^{\infty} 1/\sqrt{2\pi} \exp(-(x-mu)^2/2)dx=0.95`

We can sample Normal distribution from `dnorm(x, mean, sd)` or
`rnorm(n, mean, sd)`. But we need to first take value for `mean` and `sd`.

Comment: @JohnColeman This will be an equation about `mu`.

Comment: @JohnColeman: *mu* is the mean of a statistical distribution.

Comment: @JohnColeman I want to find the value of `mu` such that the probability `N(\mu, 1)>1.96` is 0.95.

Comment: @Hermi Your meaning is clear now, it wasn't before the edit.

Comment: I bet this can be done directly with the right invocation of `qnorm()` (see my comment below)

Comment: `qnorm(0.95, 0, 1) + 1.96`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `uniroot` to find the point where the probability equals 0.95. The function `f` is a way of writing this. The interval's  end point are arbitrary, chosen because I wasn't not expecting the solution to be much faraway from the origin.
Note the argument `lower.tail` set to FALSE.

```r
f <- function(x) {
  pnorm(1.96, mean = x, sd = 1, lower.tail = FALSE) - 0.95
}
uniroot(f, c(-5, 5))
#> $root
#> [1] 3.604879
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 2.594975e-06
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 12
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 6.103516e-05

mu <- uniroot(f, c(-5, 5))$root
mu
#> [1] 3.604879

pnorm(1.96, mu, 1)
#> [1] 0.04999741
curve(pnorm(x, mu, 1),  from = -5, to = 8)
abline(h = 0.95, lty = "dashed")
abline(v = 1.96, lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Good job! Or we can use `uniroot(function(m) qnorm(0.05, m) - 1.96, c(-3, 3))`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other options

- Using `qnorm` + `uniroot` (similar to the answer by [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71300525/12158757))

```
> uniroot(function(m) qnorm(0.05, m) - 1.96, c(-1e3, 1e3))$root
[1] 3.604854
```

- Using `erfinv` from `pracma` package

```
library(pracma)
> 1.96 + sqrt(2) * pracma::erfinv(2 * 0.95-1)
[1] 3.604854
```

Comment: and note that `erfinv` is actually very simple: `sqrt(qchisq(abs(y), 1)/2) * sign(y)`